# IOS Safari - How to download or display a pdf

Tags: javascript, ios, pdf, filesaver.js

just a simple example, I tried using `window.open`

```
    var save = 'test'
    var blob = new Blob([save], {
        type: "application/pdf;charset=utf-8"
    });
    var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    window.open(fileURL);
```

I also tried using [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/)

```
    var save = 'test'
    var blob = new Blob([save], {
        type: "application/pdf;charset=utf-8"
    });
    saveAs(blob, filename);
```

Assume the blob contains valid pdf content. It seems to work in all other browsers (including OSX safari) by downloading a pdf file.

However in both cases, it seems to open a new tab that looks like this [image]

I want to be able to do something like [this](https://file-examples.com/index.php/sample-documents-download/sample-pdf-download/) where the pdf would open in a new page