# ICS files on iOS Safari browser

Tags: javascript, filesaver.js

I'm creating an ICS file that works well with Android/Windows, but on iOS (Safari) it seems it has a problem working with downloading the file in proper format.

Using [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js) extension.

Issue was highlighted back in 2013 - https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/issues/12

Similar issue on Stack - [IOS Safari - How to download or display a pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57512011/ios-safari-how-to-download-or-display-a-pdf)

```
<script>
  const newEvent = {
    BEGIN: 'VCALENDAR',
    PRODID: 'ABC',
    UID: 'info@info.com',
    CATEGORIES: 'EVENT',
    DTSTART: '20190321T153010Z',
    DTEND: '',
    SUMMARY: 'demo',
    DESCRIPTION: 'demo',
    END:'VEVENT',
    END: 'VCALENDAR',
}

let formattedDate = formatDate(newEvent.DTSTART)

cal = ics()
cal.addEvent(newEvent.SUMMARY, newEvent.DESCRIPTION, newEvent.PRODID, formattedDate, formattedDate)

function formatDate(dateString) {
  return dateString.replace(/(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})T(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})/,"$1-$2-$3T$4:$5:$6")
}

  download_calendar_btn.onclick = function() {
    cal.download("Event")
  }


  </script>
```

What happens when clicking on the button is that instead of downloading the ICS file, on iOS it will redirect to an url as: `blob:(my url) (followed by fileid)` and say it's an unknown document.

Comment: Hi - did you get anywhere with this?